# Summarizing column in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I have data with a column containing a number value, and I want to divide the value of each feature by the total sum of all the values in the column (to get a percentage).

So I would like to know if there is some simple syntax in the QGIS field calculator to get the sum of a column, preferably without resorting to for loops and what not.

---

I have a shapefile where feature A has the value X in column B. How can I summerize the values for all features in column B in order to divide value X to get a percentage for each feature?

Comment: you can use count( "field1" , "field1" )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: QGIS 2.18 (07/07/2017):**

In the **Field Calculator**, you can use the *Aggregate* function `sum` which allows you to sum the values of a column based on an expression. You can also, optionally, group and filter features for summation. So in your field calculator, you could simply use:

```
 (sum( "column_B" ) / "column_B") * 100
```

---

---

**Original post: 23/04/2015**

You *can't* sum columns using the Field Calculator (although it would be useful in certain situations). To be able to sum columns and obtain a value, you can use:

- QGIS function - **Basic Statistics** (*Vector* > *Analysis Tools* > *Basic Statistics*)
- QGIS Plugin - **GroupStats** (*Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins*)
- QGIS Plugin - **Statist** (*Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins*)

So what I would do is create a new integer or real column (eg. "Sum") and add the value you obtain from any of the methods into the *Expression* window. Then create another column (eg. "Percentile") and edit the following expression to suit your column names:

```
("Sum" / "column_B") * 100
```

Comment: This works, although I was hoping for a more elegant solution. But I guess "you can't" is sometimes a useful answer, since you can stop looking for an elegant solution and go with the solution that actually solves the problem.

Comment: @hexamon - I know **exactly** what you mean as I always tend to look for more elegant solutions first before giving up for an alternative method (if any!).

Comment: Question: Let say I wanted to get a sum of a particular column would the syntax look like `sum($columnName)` ?

Comment: @MRDR - You're almost correct! Just remove the dollar sign :) `sum(columnName)`