# Calculating weighted values of field in Attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, calculate-values

In QGIS in the Attribute Table, I have a field with values.

For this field, I need to calculate the Sum of all its values and divide by the number of values that are not equal to `"NULL"`.

Afterwards, I need to create a new field, where each value of the original field will be divided into the previously calculated (the Sum of all its values and divided by the number of values).

Is it possible to do this with the function editor in the Field Calculator (as this action will be repeated more than once)?

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you need to create one additional field in the Attribute Table:

> `"Output"`, where the calculated new values will be stored (probably a
>   real data type).

Then you need to proceed in Expression dialogue using the following formula

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "YOUR_FIELD" <> 'NULL' THEN "YOUR_FIELD" / (sum("YOUR_FIELD") / count("YOUR_FIELD"))
    ELSE NULL
END
```

---

Let's assume we have a field with values, that vary between `3` and `300`, and also include `"NULL"` values. See the Attribute Table below.

[image: Attribute_Table]

In my case, the sum of all values is `544`. The number of values that are not equal to `"NULL"` is `7`.

Then I proceed with a formula in the Expression dialogue with activated Editing mode.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "Value" <> 'NULL' THEN "Value" / (sum("Value") / count("Value"))
    ELSE NULL
END
```

[image: Expression_Dialogue]

The output corresponding new values will look as following.

[image: Output]

---

**References:**

- [Summarizing column in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143544/summarizing-column-in-qgis-field-calculator)
- [Calculating sum of parts of column based on another column using QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/calculating-sum-of-parts-of-column-based-on-another-column-using-qgis-field-calc/183060)
- [How to group and count attribute data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70886/how-to-group-and-count-attribute-data/114655)
- [Elseif Conditional Statement in QGIS Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator)
- [Expressions in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#expressions)
- [Difference between quotation marks ('single' vs “double”) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301566/difference-between-quotation-marks-single-vs-double-in-qgis)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but my action is repeated very often and therefore I needed to create a function in the function editor.  in Expression dialogue
I also introduced the formula "Value"  /  (  sum(  "Value"  )  /  (count( CASE WHEN  "Value"  >= 1 THEN +1 END)))